# No Database Selected - Error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I work with the following example-code:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('mysql3.00*****', 'a7552070******', 'fjewifn****');
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO diequizapp(appid, itemid, data) VALUES ('John', 'bon', 'jovi')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

but I get an No Database selected back.

Can somebody please tell my why ?
I took this example from a tutorial.

Auf Wiedersehen, Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the database that you want to select data from as the last parameter in `mysqli_connect(host, username, password, database)`

You can also take the second approach and use the `mysqli_select_db($connection, DATABASE)` function

Answer (score 0):

you did not given the database name try like this

```
$dbname = "****";      //database name
$dbhost = "localhost"; // host name localhost
$dbusername = "***";  // username of the mysql
$dbpassword = "***";  // password of the mysql

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link))
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
```

then run your query........